# JupyterLab output hyperlink to execute additional code in kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I'm working with JupyterLab (v. 0.33.6 in Python 3.6), and I'm developing a wrapper kernel someone else wrote based on the IPython kernel. I'd like to be able to output a link or button that, when clicked, executes specific code in the kernel. Something like "You can plot this data" that enables the user to quickly run the code and have the output appear below the current output.

In the old Jupyter notebook (not in Jupyter lab), it was possible to do this using something like `Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute('doPlot()')`, but now there is no `Jupyter` object accessible. Is there anyway to do this? It seems like writing a custom ipywidget might be a way to accomplish this, but that might be a lot of work for a fairly simple task. I'm a novice at Javascript, any pointers or suggestions would be very helpful!